# Get a file in command line args

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to get a file in command line arguments

ex: `myapp.exe /File "C:\Path\To\File.txt"`

I've made a code that does not work :

```
myfile = CommandLineArgs(2).Remove(0, CommandLineArgs(2).IndexOf(Chr(34)))
```

And I've this error :

[image: Error : The account cannot be less than zero. Setting name: count]

> In English : The account cannot be less than zero.
> Setting name: count

Can someone help me ?

Comment: That path shouldn't contain double quotes when received through `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` or `My.Application.CommandLineArgs()`

Comment: Btw, it appears you have just two elements in `My.Application.CommandLineArgs()` (indexes `0` and `1`). So, just read `CommandLineArgs(1)` as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always have PAIRS of arguments, then you could use code like this:

```
Private myfile As String

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim args() As String = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs
    ' The executable itself is at args(0), so we start a 1 below:
    For i As Integer = 1 To (args.Length - 2) Step 2
        Select Case args(i).ToUpper
            Case "/FILE"
                myfile = args(i + 1)
                Debug.Print("myfile = " & myfile)

            Case "/OTHEROPTION"
                ' ... code ...

            Case Else
                Debug.Print("Unknown argument: " & args(i))
                Debug.Print("Unknown value: " & args(i + 1))
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```